# Django ModelAdmin get_form 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to add a new field to ModelAdmin, but get an error:

```
@admin.register(FilmWork)
class FilmworkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fields = ('title', 'plot', 'ratings', 'film_creation_date', 'age_limit', 'link')
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form_factory = super(FilmworkAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form_factory.base_fields['Actors'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), required=False)
```

The error says:

```
    form = ModelForm(initial=initial)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I do not initialise any modelform anywhere.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you should [return the model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) class from the `get_form`  method

Comment: that actually worked! thank you! But I do not see this new fied on the website :(

Comment: yes @AbdulNiyasPM is correct (you should return form_factory from get_form) and you should read the existing function definition before you override it, as it will be helpful to understand the issue if any. Good luck

Comment: In my experience, the correct way of doing this is to create a forms.py file in your app, define a form class there and use that in FilmworkAdmin. This way you do not need to override get_form.

Comment: since I am new to django and need to solve my task quikly, I am afraid it will take too much time util I understand how to prperly prepare forms.py, but that looks like a proper way to do it! so i will consider this in the future, thank you! Do you by any chance know why do I not see the new field that I added in the online form?

Comment: try adding "Actors" to fields in FilmworkAdmin

Comment: it says that Filmwork does not have field actors, I tried also changing the order of fields and get_form, didn't help

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM has already answered this - you've grabbed your form, called if `form_factory`, added a value, now you need to `return form_factpory`

Comment: yes, I do it, I do not get error anymore, but I also do not see my new fields on the website

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved the problem - one needs to create a form and a custom save method:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    actor = Person.objects.filter(role='actor')
    writer = Person.objects.filter(role='writer')
    director = Person.objects.filter(role='director')
    actors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, queryset=actor, required=False)
    writers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, queryset=writer, required=False)
    directors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, queryset=director, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FilmWork
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(FilmWork)
class FilmworkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = MyModelForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', 'plot', 'ratings', 'film_creation_date', 'age_limit', 'link', 'actors', 'writers', 'directors'),
        }),
    )
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        q1 = form.cleaned_data.get('actors', None)
        q2 = form.cleaned_data.get('writers', None)
        q3 = form.cleaned_data.get('directors', None)
        q1 = q1.union(q2).union(q3)
        obj.person_set.set(q1)
```